# prapareForSegue cannot set any property for destination controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this weird problem where I cannot set properties for destination view. I have done it thousand times.
This is the code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"InboxSegue"]){
        InboxViewController *controller = (InboxViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.ERA = ERA;

    }

}
```

I have initialised all properties in both controller. I did debugging and all variable have values and not nil.

The error:
ReadLater[43713:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setERA:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10976e760'

Comment: can u post your full code? we want see what your ERA.

Comment: In firstviewcontroller where u define ERA

Comment: I have posted 1st controller. thank u.

Comment: whether your inboxviewcontroller selected tags and firstviewcontroller selected tags are of same type?

Comment: @Kathiravan G, I appreciate you trying to help. Desdenova gave answer that works. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error reason tells that your segue's destination view controller is actually a navigation controller.

So you need to reach your view controller within it's navigation stack like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"InboxSegue"]){

        UINavigationController * navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        InboxViewController * inboxViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        inboxViewController.ERA = ERA;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem is that I simply did not know that there is difference between Navigation controller and usual for segues. I got minus vote for this question. Is that really so bad question? (if so, I would not post such anymore)

Comment: Note that whatever you hook to your segue's end is always your destination view controller. It could be a navigation controller, tab bar controller or any other view controller type. The visible view controller is another story depending on the parent controller. Class reference has detailed information on how you access it's items for any type.

Comment: Alright, I will pay more time to look at references from now on. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Check If you have assigned "InboxSegue" to the particular controller properly, It occurs when `segue.destinationViewController` gives some other controller then the expected one